# Is there a way to make a git repository commit a directory before a pull/clone?

Tags: git, githooks

Sorry if I am completely wrong or anything, I am really new to Git and I am trying to write up a way for my work (website development/hosting) to implement it. Everybody here has been here for like 15 years and they really haven't changed how they do anything. Lately a coworker and I have been trying to get things up to day and I think we would really, REALLY benefit from using git. The problem is that everybody is against change so I have to make it easy...

From a little googling I found a way (http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto) that looks like it might almost work without really messing up every bodies workflow, but there is a problem with it.

Right now the setup is
Website repos on local network drive, `W:\Git\` (maybe on the server root later?)
And websites on a server running windows over VPN, `\\172.16.xxx.xxx\data_www`

This works fine (except for being a little slow) but it looks like if anybody makes a change to the actual website files then we would lose them.

My idea was reject the push if the pushing repository is being in commits and to intercept git pull/git clone and automatically commit the contents of the website folder before continuing with the pull/clone. This way people can still make changes, but we wont lose any data accidentally... but I don't see any hooks where I could use just `git commit -m "Add live site changes"` that look like they might work and I am a little stumped.

I liked the concept of just sending out an email that says

To make changes to websites

Run `git clone W:\Git\Domain.tld.git C:\Git` in a command line
make any changes to the website in `C:\Git\Domain.tld`,
save the changes with `git commit -m "Description"`
update the live website with `git push`

Is there a correct way to do this? If not is there any other way to set things up that keeps people from having to alter their workflow too much?
Thanks!!

Comment: Repeat after me: "`git` is not a deployment tool". Granted there are a lot of people who try to shoehorn it into being one, as evidenced by the sheer number of questions here about "I'm using `git` to deploy, but blah blah blah...". Most of those would be resolved by not trying to force a `git` solution in a problem space it was never designed for... </soapbox>

Comment: People are making changes to the live site without making those changes locally first, committing, pushing and resolving conflicts etc. *before* the changes go up to production? Ouch.

Comment: The current process is make changes to live website at non peak hours. We have over 300 websites, with probably 260-280 of them based on one of two of our websites. I started here relatively recently and before Git the upgrade/update process was basically crawl through every file or look for notes on some ancient knowledge base. I started using git just for diff to upgrade/update websites, I want to really implement it now though. I kind of took over development of our main site, I started using git about a year ago for that. I really want to get every other website tracked too but Idk how...

Comment: In addition to the comment by @bcmcfc : If they have been doing it during the last 15 years, consider leaving that job and finding a more promising one. )

Answer (score 0):

There may well be a technical answer here concerning how to make git do what you want, but in the meantime, let's forget about that and go after the root cause of the problem.

People shouldn't be making uncommitted, untested changes to the production site outside of usual development workflow.

(related: see [gitflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) for a means of working with git that, among other things, provides a means for patching production with hotfixes)

The problem you have is this way of doing things has been prevalent for a long time in the organisation you find yourself working in. Long enough that change resistence may prevent you from getting anywhere.

The way I see it you have two options. Look for another job or try and convince them to change.

The latter will be hard but isn't impossible. If you can, find examples of where their current practices has caused a real issue for a client, or perhaps has broken a sales demo that's resulted in loss of business. Make sure the people responsible for making decisions are aware of the link between bad development practice and those negative consequences. Explain how an alternative way of working prevents that from happening and would be straightforward to implement.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I think my biggest problem is I don't know what the best solution is. I just started using git, finally got my coworkers interested, and they gave me the task of finding a way to use it without messing up their routine.

Comment: It's the "messing up their routine" part that's going to be a struggle. If their routine is flawed it needs messing with! Convincing them of that is tricky though.